how should i include description in payment Intent in stripe integration with medusa backend
i am integrating stripe in react native and backend is medusa store. now to accept international payment, i need to include description as a part of paymentIntent.
how should it be done in Medusa backend store.
how should i access the payment Intent in medusa store and modify it to include description field , so that stripe will accept it as an international payment
